# NSNotification for Mission Control

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

Is it possible to receive a notification in a Cocoa app for when Mission Control is launched?

I tried the following with no success:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notify:) name:NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)notify:(NSNotification *)notifcation {
    NSLog(@"mission control called");
}
```

Comment: I would guess no, but there's a way to check. First, though, if you're using `NSWorkspace...` notifications, you have to register with the workspace notification center (`-[NSWorkspace notificationCenter]`), not the standard center. The way to check is to register with the standard notification center, the distributed notification center (`NSDistributedNotificationCenter`), and the workspace notification center for *all* notifications (`nil` name, `nil` sender). Then log what happens when you enter Mission Control. However, what you find may be undocumented/unsupported and subject to change.

Comment: @KenThomases Would your approach be accepted for an app that is submitted to the app store?

Comment: Well, what I suggested was just a technique for exploring. It's a way to find out what notification, if any, is posted when you enter Mission Control. If you find such a notification (which I doubt) and you build an app that listens specifically for that, well, I have no idea if it would be accepted. I would guess it's OK, but that's not worth much.

Comment: @KenThomases I'll start checking the notifications and see if I find anything. In the mean time, hopefully someone will post an answer, if one exists.